# strtolower не срабатывает с латиницей

Tags: php, robots.txt

Есть задача взять файл "robots.txt" с указанного пользователем адреса, и найти в нём кол-во директив "Host". Файл "robots.txt" например -

```
 User-agent: Yandex 
 Disallow: /
 host: example.com
 host: example2.com
```

Файл беру с удалённого сервера по запросу пользователя и кодировка с символами могут быть любые.
Чтобы не привязываться к регистру символов пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$url = 'http://tests.loc/robots.txt';
$maxsize = 32768;
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 10)));  
$directives = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx, -1, $maxsize);  
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");  
echo strtolower($directives); //Возвращает ту же строку без изменения регистра символов 
echo substr_count($directives, 'host');
```

Подскажите что не так? Или может такую задачу можно решить иначе

Comment: Как именно "не срабатывает"? Возвращает ту же строку без изменения регистра символов? Если файл действительно содержит не-ASCII текст, то можно воспользоваться mb_strtolower()

Comment: в редакторе кнопка `{}` означает вставку кода. Пожалуйста используйте её.

Comment: Naumov понял, спасибо. astax, да возвращает ту же строку без изменения регистра символов. mb_strtolower() тоже не помогает, mb_internal_encoding()  устанавливал. Файл беру с удалённого сервера по запросу пользователя и кодировка с символами могут быть любые ведь